# UniqueValidator with source field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and serializer:

```
email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email', required=False,
                                  validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
```

Serialization works fine, but deserialization doesn't — it tries to file 'user.email' field in User model, and, of course, fails.

If I change User to UserProfile in the queryset, it fails with another error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin@localhost'

Is it possible to set different sources for serialization and deserialization?

Comment: Try to use custom field in serializer http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `UniqueValidator` expects that the `source` (or field name, if no `source` is given) can be used in the `queryset` that is provided to [filter out the existing object](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/0cbfbc27d838730f8238b3fd2d973369ca81d379/rest_framework/validators.py#L42-L47). So by using a source that spans a relation (and has a dot), it will try to use that name when filtering the queryset which fails, as you've noticed.

You can fix this by subclassing `UniqueValidator` to override the `filter_queryset` method to filter it differently.

```
class CustomUniqueValidator(UniqueValidator):

    def filter_queryset(self, value, queryset):
        """
        Filter the queryset to all instances matching the given attribute.
        """
        filter_kwargs = {"email": value}
        return queryset.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

This hard codes `email` as the filter, one possible option for not hard coding it would be to split `self.field_name` and get the last part of the dotted source.